# linearizing a non linear state space equation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, modeling, mathematics

I have this 1-DOF helicopter simulator.

[image]

The motor's armature resistance is $R$, inductance $L$ and motor constant $K$ and reaction torque on the motor shaft is $τ$. $T$ is equal to $k_1w_2^2$ and $\tau$ is equal to $k_2w_2^2$.

$$w_1 = \dot{\varphi}_1$$

$$w_2=\dot{\theta}$$

Τhe differential equation for the current is:

$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}=\frac{E - RI - K_1w_2}{L}$$

in which $E$ is the input armature voltage and the equation for the torque is

$$\frac{\partial w_2}{\partial t}=\frac{KI - K_2w_2^2}{J} $$

in which $k_2w_2^2$ is the load torque and finally for the last equation I used lagrange method to derive equation of motion of mass $m$ and $M$.

$$ T = \frac{1}{2}mb^2\dot{\varphi}^2 + \frac{1}{2}M\alpha^2\dot{\varphi}^2 + \frac{1}{2}Jw_2^2 $$

$$ U = mgb\sin\varphi - Μg\alpha\sin\varphi $$

which finally gives

$$ mb^2\dot{w} + M\alpha^2\dot{w}_1 + bmg\cos\varphi - Mg\alpha\cos\varphi = -Tb = K_1w_2^2b $$

$$ \frac{\partial w_1}{\partial t} = \frac{-k_1w_1^2 + Mg\alpha\cos\varphi - mgb\cos\varphi}{M\alpha^2 + mb^2} $$

I wanna know whether everything here is right and how to linearize it around $\varphi = 0$ cause when I try to do that $\dfrac{\partial w_1}{\partial t}$ becomes a constant which is:

$$ \frac{\partial w_1}{\partial t} = \frac{Mg\alpha - mgb}{M\alpha^2 + mb^2} $$

Comment: Please do some formatting, this is too difficult to read.

Comment: I edited like everything in order to be able for anyone to read it. When you post here don't expect an answer no matter what but help everyone else by making your post as clear as possible. For the linearization around $\phi$ you can take Taylor's series for $sinφ$ and $cosφ$ around zero.

Comment: ok, youre right but first deriative of cos will be sin which will be zero at 0 and f(0) will be d(w1)/dt=(Mga-mgb)/)Ma^2+mb^2, as you can see its constant and it doesn't depend on any state variable or inputs, is it wrong?

Comment: The linearization of $sinx$ around zero is not $0$. Search taylor series of $cosx$ and $sinx$. And insert mathjax equations at your comments as well.

Comment: it's not sinx, it's cosx as i added just now in the post and it's not zero it's a constant which also i added at the end of the post

Answer (score 3):

The Lagrangian for your 1D pitch system is $\mathcal{L} := T - U$, which is

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(mb^2 + Ma^2)\dot{\phi}^2 + \frac{1}{2}J\dot{\theta}^2 + (Ma - mb)g\sin\phi
$$

The Euler-Lagrange Equations are

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}_k}\bigg) + \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q_k} = Q_k
$$
This gives the EOM

$$
(mb^2 + Ma^2)\ddot{\phi} + (Ma - mb)g\cos\phi = -Tb = -k_1\dot{\theta}^2b
$$
Under a small angle approximation, $\cos\phi \approx 1$, so this leaves

$$
(mb^2 + Ma^2)\ddot{\phi} + (Ma - mb)g = -k_1b\dot{\theta}^2,
$$
or in another form,
$$
\ddot{\phi} = \frac{mb-Ma}{mb^2 + Ma^2}g - \frac{k_1b}{mb^2 + Ma^2}\dot{\theta}^2 = \beta_1 - \beta_2\dot{\theta}^2.
$$
Now, I don't know if these are the correct equations for your system, but based on what you outlined in your question, this is what the EOM are for $\phi(t)$.

You also have a coupled system of ODE's for $I(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ since from $\dot{\theta} = \omega_2$ it follows that

$$
\begin{align}
\ddot{\theta} &= \frac{K}{J}I - \frac{k_2}{J}\dot{\theta}^2\\
\dot{I} &= \frac{E}{L} - \frac{R}{L}I - \frac{k_1}{L}\dot{\theta}
\end{align}
$$

Again, this is all based off your model that you wrote in the problem statement. So, in total, you have three ODE's for the three variables $\theta,\phi,I$. Given that this system of 3 ODE's is nonlinear, there is no analytical solution. What you can do to simulate this is solve the system in MATLAB for example using ODE45 or just any differential equaton solver.

---

If you want to linearize this system, you can do the following. First, put the system in state space form, i.e. let $x = [\phi,\dot{\phi},\theta,\dot{\theta},I]^\intercal$ so that the *full* dynamics are

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2\\
\dot{x}_2 &= \beta_1\cos x_1 - \beta_2 x_4^2\\
\dot{x}_3 &= x_4\\
\dot{x}_4 &= \frac{K}{J}x_5 - \frac{k_2}{J}x_4^2\\
\dot{x}_6 &= \frac{E}{L} - \frac{R}{L}x_5 - \frac{k_1}{L}x_4.
\end{align}
$$
Notice that the nonlinear equations are the second one and the fourth one. So right now you system like $\dot{x} = f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a nonlinear function (5 by 1 vector). To linearize this sytem into the form $\dot{x} = Ax$, you can set

$$
A = \bigg[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg]_0,
$$
evaluated at some *nominal* conditions, which will give a 5 by 5 matrix. In your case this gives

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-\beta_1\sin x_1 & 0 & 0 & -2\beta_2 x_4 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2\frac{k_2}{J}x_4 & \frac{K}{J}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{k_1}{L} & -\frac{R}{L}
\end{bmatrix}_0
$$
So you need to come up with some reference point for linearization for $\phi$ and $\dot{\theta}$, and then you can simulate the linearized system.

Comment: this is exactly what i derived too which is nonlinear, you mean it can't be linearized? especially ϕ¨

Comment: Let me edit my response real quick to show you a method to linearize.

Comment: You should maybe add that for the process you are proposing, you first need to find the system's equilibrium points and then linearize around one of these equilibrium points. These points are not reference points, you can't just pick them randomly.

Comment: Yes exactly what @TeoProtoulis said. The reference points are not arbitrary.

Comment: I see now also that the derived $A$ matrix is not linear with respect to the state variables. There is a $sin(x_1)$ term which is nonlinear.

Comment: it's not arbitrary that's true because it should be the point at which Xdot=0 am i right? here is full description of problem https://ibb.co/6v6STCN is it possible that it's wrong or something?

Comment: You need to find the state space equations and linearize them around $x_1=0$ (supposing that in state-space form $x_1=\phi$).

Comment: yes and when i try to do that as i mentioned  ϕ¨ becomes a constant which doesn't have any of the state variables in it

Comment: Not necessarily. Your equilibrium condition will be when the thrust completely balances out gravity so the equilibrium angular velocity of the rotor is NOT zero.

Comment: I have to mention again that the derived matrix $A$ is not linear with respect to the state variables which means that the state equations are not linear as asked at the problem statement.

Comment: You are forgetting that you have to plug in values for the state variables into $A$. This is the usual way to linearize nonlinear systems, by taking the gradient at the nominal conditions.

Comment: Oh yes of course I am sorry, didn't notice you hadn't plugged in the values for the equilibrium point.

Comment: @JoshPilipovsky i think we are finding whare's wrong, about angular velocity not being zero can you explain more cause i thought Xdot should be zero which has angular velocity in it.

Comment: so you mean by putting w1dot zero and ϕ=0 we get a value for w2(equilibirum) and then we get a value for I(equilibrium) by putting w2dot zero and from that we get a value for E. and finally we can linearize it without problem. but can you explain why Xdot shouldn't necessarily zero?

Comment: When performing the linearization, you don’t necessarily have to do it about $x = 0$. You linearize about nominal conditions. In your problem, your “nominal” is when the beam or whatever is straight and level. This corresponds to a pitch $\phi_0 = 0$. However, when it is level, the motor is still spinning so the thrust is nonzero and as such, there is a nonzero nominal angular velocity, $\dot{\theta}_0 \neq 0$.

Comment: i considered it nonzero and tried to linearize it but a constant term appears along with a function of state variables, is it normal? how can we show it in matrix form then?

Comment: Well, what I can't find out is how the equilibrium point of the nonlinear state space equations is $0$ since the second state space equation involves $\cos(x_1)$ which is zero for $\frac{pi}{2}$ (and its multipliers).

Comment: this is how i convinced myself, in equilibrium point all the forces should cancel each other so both ϕ¨  and θ¨ must be zero . then we'll obtain a value for ϕdot(equilibrium) and I(equilibrium) by assigning ϕ to zero in two of the equations.then we can linearize every nonlinear equation, but the question is when we try to linearize it a constant term (independent of state variables) appears and it can't be shown in matrix form. i wanna know whether it's normal or not.

Comment: In order to find the equilibrim point for a system, you need to set all state space equations equal to $0$. Doing so for the nonlinear state equations gives a value for $x_1 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ which is not applicable to this particular system.

Comment: setting Xdot which is matrix equal to zero gives x2=x4=0 which then gives x1=π/2, you're right but x2 and x4 aren't necessarily  zero which means we can obtain a value for them as well as I and E by setting x2dot and x4dot equal to zero.